# how can i convert a type of column in a table of postgres to serial data type?

Tags: python, sql

i'm a beginner in python and low level in english.
so forgive me if i make any mistakes.
i created a table in postgresql .that table has a column that is primary key and i forgot to insert a serial type to it .
now i want to edit it .how can i do this?

i try this :
ALTER TABLE request
ALTER COLUMN id_request type serial;

but i get :
ERROR:  type "serial" does not exist

i can't drop a create again that column because it is a foreign key to another table